# Port Forwarding(?) TD-W8961nd

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have a bit of a weird internet setup. I am connected via a decent WiFi connection (from work) which I pick up using a Buffalo Airstation Wireless-G box. This simply picks up the signal and gives me 4 ethernet ports to connect to. That's all fine and works as it should.

I also have a TP LINK TD-W8961nd router which *used* to be connected to the Airstation via an ethernet cable so I could essentially have WiFi access in my house. To cut a long story short I can't remember how the hell I got it to work and I can't find the notes I scribbled down on how to do it. I'm pretty sure I need to tell the router what ip to pick up the internet connection from and have the local wifi as a seperate network. How the hell I do that I have no idea right now.

Can anyone give me some advice on this? If you need more information ask and I will be able to do so.

Cheers in advance.

**edit**

I'm in work at the moment so I can't give 100% details but I will be able to later on.

Comment: So how far have you gotten, how are things currently attached, and where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: I will update a bit later when I get home from work.

Comment: Okay, sorry for late reply. I am not entirely sure how to set any of it up any more. The WiFi works... as in I can connect to the router with various devices. However the router is not getting an internet connection that is provided by the Airstation which is plugged into port 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up picking up a cable router. Problem solved. I'm pretty sure the router I had was on it's last legs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your TP-Link router should have a seperate port labeled 'uplink' or 'modem', which you need to connect to the Buffalo. From there, you can configure the TP-Link to get an IP address via DHCP. You also need to turn on DHCP and NAT on the TP-Link.

Comment: The backpanel of the router looks like this:
[link](http://uk.tp-link.com/resources/images/products/large/TD-W8961ND-04.jpg). 4 ethernet (RJ45) ports and 1 line in (RJ11). The link from/to the Buffalo is from an ethernet cable.

Comment: Although saying that, I could easily get a RJ45->RJ11 adaptor/cable maybe.

Comment: That sounds like the TP-Link is an ADSL Router, rather than a Cable Router. You will need a cable router to achive what you describe.

Comment: Yeah it is an ADSL router. It's just annoyiong how I have managed to get it working in the past. Still, I am going to nick my partner's little router and have a play with that over the weekend.